# Facebook jQuery Logout using Logout URL and Access Token

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, logout

When a user logs out of my site, unless they also log out of their Facebook account, they remain logged in to my site.

I'd like to comply with point 6 of this policy, so how can I log my users out of my site and out of their Facebook accounts for security https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

I have the following code bound to my login button and it's not working - the user is still logged in to FB after clicking. My console shows that the var accessToken is not defined but I'm not sure why. I'm sure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, would really appreciate some help!

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $(".logout").click(function () {
   FB.init({appId : <?php echo $this->config->item('facebook_appid');?>,
     status : true,
     cookie : true,
     oauth : true,
     frictionlessRequests: true});

   FB.login(function(response) {
     if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log(response.authResponse.accessToken);
     var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
     }
     });

   window.location.replace("https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1&next=http://www.mysite.com&access_token="+accessToken+"");

});
});
  </script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To log out of Facebook, you need to use the [`FB.logout()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/) method.

If you have already called the `FB.init()` and the `FB.login()` methods, you don't need to call these again in your click function.

Comment: Thankyou I had tried FB.logout() in a different and was looking for alternatives, but just trying this very simple solution bound to my logout button worked nicely :-)

Comment: how to pass access token for FB.logout() ?